# PostgreSQL 9.4 - select dynamic subset of JSONB fields

Tags: postgresql-9.4

Suppose I have table with some JSONB column. JSON is rather huge, and in most of the cases I need to retrieve just 5% of its content by field names (just to improve performance). Set of the needed fields varies from case to case, but it is still around 5% of whole JSON data.

I know how to do this for hardcoded set of fields. The question is - is it possible to make for externally provided set of fields. This needs to be implemented as stored function.

Here is sample with 'hardcoded set of fields':

```
CREATE TABLE test_data (
  json_data jsonb NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test_data(json_data)
VALUES ('{"row_id": 1, "f1": 1, "f2": 2, "f3": 3, "f4": 4}'),
       ('{"row_id": 2, "f1": 1, "f2": 2, "f3": 3, "f4": 4}');


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_important_data(IN data_set varchar = 'row_id,f1,f2')
  RETURNS table (data json)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY 
  SELECT (SELECT row_to_json(data_row) FROM (
        -- this needs to be dynamic
        select json_data->>'row_id' as "row_id",
               json_data->>'f1' as "f1",
               json_data->>'f2' as "f2"
      ) data_row ) as data
  FROM test_data;
END $$;

SELECT get_important_data(/* use default data set*/);
SELECT get_important_data('row_id,f2,f4');
```

Answer (score 0):

While I think (I'm not sure though) you could get away without any dynamic SQL and some cumbersome joins and pivot-like queries, I think the most straightforward and possibly performing way here is a little dynamic query in your function.

This would be my quick take on your solution. Note the explicit conversion to `text`, to recreate the effect of your `->>` operator:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_important_data(data_set text DEFAULT 'row_id,f1,f2') RETURNS TABLE (
    data    json
) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT row_to_json(j.*) FROM test_data, LATERAL jsonb_to_record(json_data) AS j(%s);', 
        (SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(trim(field)), ' text, ') || ' text'
            FROM unnest(string_to_array(data_set, ',')) AS field)
    );
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But in my opinion, since you are ultimately returning a subset of a `json` filed still in `json` format, you'd better leave it untouched. I like the following version more, and it should run faster too:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_important_data(data_set text DEFAULT 'row_id,f1,f2') RETURNS TABLE (
    data    json
) AS $$
DECLARE
    rec_fields  record;
    arr_fields  text[];
BEGIN
    FOR rec_fields IN 
        SELECT trim(unnest(string_to_array(data_set, ','))) AS field 
    LOOP
        arr_fields :=  arr_fields || format('json_data->%1$L AS %1$I', rec_fields.field);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT row_to_json(r) FROM (SELECT %s FROM test_data) AS r', array_to_string(arr_fields, ','));
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The final touch would be dropping that `text` input parameter in favour of a `json` one *(`'["row_id", "f1", "f2"]'`)*, but I'll leave that for you.